# MY JList cannot React with another Jlist, in other word, they dont connect somehow, when i click on 2nd jlist it value is null

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist, listselectionlistener

How to make 3 `JList` that connect each other?

```
private JList style = new JList(new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday","Saturday","Sunday" });

private JList style2 = new JList(new String[] {"Lucy","bin"});
```

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
        updateFont();

```
}


  public void updateFont() {

      String m = (String) style.getSelectedValue();
      System.out.println(m);

    if(style.getSelectedValue()== "Monday")
    {
        style2.setListData(new String[]{"Lucy"});
        String mn = (String) style2.getSelectedValue();
        System.out.println(mn);
        //style3.setListData(st.getTime(mn));

    }
    if(style.getSelectedValue()== "Tuesday")
    {
        style2.setListData(new String[]{"Lucy"});               
    }

    if(style.getSelectedValue()== "Wednesday")
    {
        style2.setListData(st.getMovieList());              
    }

    if(style.getSelectedValue()== "Thursday")
    {
        style2.setListData(st.getMovieList());              
    }

    if(style.getSelectedValue()== "Friday")
    {
        style2.setListData(st.getMovieList());              
    }

    if(style.getSelectedValue()== "Saturday")
    {
        style2.setListData(new String[] {"Lucy","bin"});                
    }
    if(style.getSelectedValue()== "Sunday")
    {
        style2.setListData(new String[] {"Lucy","bin"});                
    }

    repaint();
```

Comment: And how are they suppose to be connected?

Comment: when we click at the 1st list the second list are react, same goes to 2nd and third, i want to make, my source only go to 2nd list,and  when i click the 2nd list, it give null value

Comment: Start by taking a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). You'll want to play around with the `ListSelectionListener`...

Comment: the mn show value null :(

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: Whe should it be anyone else, once you change the list data, the selection is invalidated...